# Counting the number of binary strings of length m with no consecutive 1s (RR). How to improve it?

Tags: combinatorics, difference-equations

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to solve this problem of counting the number of binary strings of a certain length m, as far as no consecutive 1s are there.

For instance m = 3, my recurrence relation should give 5 i.e. 000, 001, 101, 100, 010.

I started like this with initial seeds: n > 0; a[ 1] = 1, a[2] = 3, a[3] = 5 and then in RSolve I did:

[image]

Is there a better way to improve it so that I can use the output in a plot? Currently, I cannot as my solution says it cannot be used as function.

Thanks.

Comment: `Fibonacci[#+2]&`

Comment: @ciao could you explain? I am new to this and some syntax is still strange to me. Thanks :)

Comment: That is a pure function, so you'd use it like so `Fibonacci[#+2]&[somevalue]` where `somevalue` is your input. If you're just plotting, simpler to just plot `Fibonacci[x+2]` directly for the range of `x` (lengths of binary string) you're after. (See my answer for example).

Comment: Note that you should use `==` and not `=` to define equations. The latter is for assignments instead. Note also that your initial conditions are inconsistent with your definition: a[3] should be a[2]+a[1] according to your recurrence equation, which should be equal to 4, but you define it equal to 5 instead.

Comment: I note that `a` is colored black in your screenshot, which means it already had a previous value assigned (likely due to your error of using) `=` instead of `==` within `RSolve[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per comment:

```
DiscretePlot[Fibonacci[x + 2], {x, 1, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"String Length", "Number with no 1 runs"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First off, you should use `==` and not `=` to define equations. The latter is for assignments.

Note also that your initial conditions are inconsistent with your definition: `a[3]` should be `a[2]+a[1]` according to your recurrence equation, i.e. 4, but you correctly define it equal to 5.

Let's check what the correct numbers should be by construction. For each value of $m$ we construct all possible runs of $m$ binary digits as a list ([`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)), then discard those with runs of ones ([`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)), then count the remaining ones ([`Length`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html)), and list those counts as a function of the number of digits:

```
TableForm[
  Table[{m, Length@DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1}, {m}], {___, 1, 1, ___}]}, {m, 5}],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"m", "seq"}}
]
```

[image: table of correct values for relation]

As [@ciao insightfully pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221130/27951), this can be expressed as `Fibonacci[m + 2]`:

```
TableForm[
  Table[{m, Length@DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1}, {m}], {___, 1, 1, ___}], Fibonacci[m + 2]}, {m, 5}],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"m", "seq", "Fibonacci[m+2]"}}
]
```

[image: comparison with Fibonacci sequence]

---

With the correct boundary values, `RSolve` does return a solution, but not as one as straightforward as the one @ciao found:

```
RSolve[
  {a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[1] == 2, a[2] == 3, a[3] == 5},
  a[n], n
]

(* Out: {{a[n] -> (1/2)*(3 Fibonacci[n] + LucasL[n])}} *)
```